# 3 Row Grid w/ Vertically Centered Children

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm stuck trying to vertically center two stacklayout children in a 3 row grid. Specifically, vertically centering the top stack in the area above the middle grid, and the bottom stack in the area below the middle grid.

Here's what I'm trying to do: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BJ0Q.png)

Here's the code:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto">

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                 Orientation="Horizontal" 
                 HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FixedRepairProfiles}">
    </StackLayout>

    <controls:VehiclePanelGrid Grid.Row="1"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding VehiclePanels}"
                               Command="{Binding SelectCommand}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                               LongPressCommand="{Binding ClearCommand}"/>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" 
                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding PanelRepairProfiles}">
    </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

Here's what I'm getting: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQYjm.png)

Comment: What is wrong with the layout in the screenshot?  The XAML you posted does not appear to bear any relation so the UI in the screenshot.

Comment: I want the two stacklayouts to be vertically centered in the areas above/below the center grid. I'll edit original post with more complete XAML.

Comment: try using CenterAndExpand

Comment: Result is the same.

Comment: @unsane try with: `<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto" VerticalOptions="Center">`

Comment: Just double-check your request, the first image is what you want, which means vertically center the "Hail" label and radio buttons? I assumed that post a simple sample with all the codes would be easier to try, otherwise, we have to suggest by guessing the result.

Comment: @Cfun That actually shrinks the grid vertically compressing all children.

Comment: @Shaw Good idea. I think I'll put together a complete XAML page using simple controls.

Comment: @unsane you tried with `CenterAndExpand` also ?

Comment: @Cfun Yes, I tried `CenterAndExpand`.

Comment: @unsane Hi, you need to set `HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"` for the inside control of `StackLayout`. However, I can not see the `DataTemplate` of `StackLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From shared xaml code, we can not make sure the inside control also will show center vertically and horizontally.

Here is the sample code to explain that:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto">
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="Silver" >
        <Label Text="First label" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Second label" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    BackgroundColor="SeaShell"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Third Label" />
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

The effect:

[image]

You will see that the first Grid if set `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` for the inside `Label`, then it will show center vertically and horizontally.